# how to add nested add fields by using angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jsp

When I click on the `add-field` button, I need to get another `add-2nd-field` button. If I click on the add-2nd-field button, I should get 3 text boxes this should repeat for 10 times upon clicking those buttons. Presently I'm getting only for the add-field button this buttons working properly. Inner `add-2nd-field` button is not working.

Please help me out.

### script code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
var add_button      = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
var y=1;
var x = 1;//initlal text box count
$(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
        x++; //text box increment
      $(wrapper).append('<div class="input_fields_wrap" id="seconddiv"><button class="add_field_button" id="secondclick">2nd add field</button><a href="#" class="remove_field"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i></a></div>'); 

    }
});

$(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text                                                                              e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
})});
```

### html code

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
<button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button></div>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: where is angular code?

Comment: you have tagged `angularjs` with `jquery` code written :D

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your code.

JS code:

```
var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
var add_button      = jQuery(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID
var x = 1;//initlal text box count
jQuery('.add_field_button').on( "click", function(e) {
   if(x <= max_fields) {
        jQuery(this).html('Add Field '+(x+1));
        jQuery('.input_fields_wrap').prepend('<p>Field '+x+' added</p>');
        x++;
   } else {
    jQuery(this).addClass('hide');
    alert('Maximum limit reached');
   }
});
```

HTML code is mostly same as yours

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
<button class="add_field_button">Add 1st Field</button>
</div>
```

CSS code

```
.hide {display: none;}
```

You can edit prepend element to your desired html. Hope it helps